# Getting a error issue from Microsoft Portal azure active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting this error message from microsoft azure portal in notification.

> The portal is having issues getting an authentication token. The
> experience rendered may be degraded.
>
> Additional information from the call to get a token: Extension:
> Microsoft_AAD_Devices Resource: microsoft.graph Details: The logged in
> user is not authorized to fetch tokens for extension
> 'Microsoft_AAD_Devices' because the user account is not a member of
> tenant 'f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a'. Error details:
> AADSTS50020: User account '{EmailHidden}' from identity provider
> 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and cannot
> access the application 'c44b4083-3bb0-49c1-b47d-974e53cbdf3c'(Azure
> Portal) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external
> user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different
> Azure Active Directory user account. Trace ID:
> 413061e1-2c1d-4890-a627-b433d2445000 Correlation ID:
> 09150c16-6f71-426b-9c88-8559a286d9a2 Timestamp: 2022-03-21 04:26:32Z

Before I was getting this message my application which was a daemon node js application was working fine and was not giving me 401 error which I am getting now since this error appeared. Not able to troubleshoot it. My code is as follow

```
require('dotenv').config();

const yargs = require('yargs');

const fetch = require('./fetch');
const auth = require('./auth');



async function main() {
            try {
                // here we get an access token
                const authResponse = await auth.getToken(auth.tokenRequest);
                console.log(authResponse.accessToken);
                // call the web API with the access token
                let users = await fetch.callApi(auth.apiConfig.uri, authResponse.accessToken);

                // display result
                console.log(users);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

    
    
};

main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AADSTS50020: User account '{EmailHidden}' from identity provider
> 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and cannot
> access the application 'c44b4083-3bb0-49c1-b47d-974e53cbdf3c'(Azure
> Portal) in that tenant.

When you are redirected to sign into the application, you might have an active session that uses a **different** personal account or organization account or uses a personal guest account.

To check where the issue lies check **User account** and **Identity provider values** in the error message.

***To resolve the error, sign out from the active session and sign in with a new incognito window or any different browser***.

Please find this link if it is helpful :

[Error AADSTS50020 - User account from identity provider does not exist in tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist#cause-3-signed-in-to-the-wrong-tenant)

Comment: thanks this helped a lot. Though my team cancelled the idea of using one drive but yet I learned something new.